# It has been years since

Tags: traducción, tiempos-verbales, conjugación

How would I say "It has been years since I've spoken Spanish on a daily basis."?

1. Hacen años que hablo el Español diariamente.
2. Hacen años que **no** hablo el Español diariamente.
3. Hacen años que he hablado...
4. Hace años que **no** he hablado...

Something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way would be: *[**Hace**](http://elblogdegramatica.blogspot.mx/2013/07/los-marcadores-temporales-hace-desde.html) años que no hablo español diariamente*.

When it refers to time, you don’t inflect *hacer* by number — this means that you would never say *hacen*, even if the phrase is referring to a period of time in plural units. You can conjugate it in past as well, such as in this example:

*¡**Hacía** años que no **hablaba** español diariamente!*

Comment: Great, thanks for the tip on the pluralization.  I was thinking that hablar should be negated but I wasn't sure.  So, without the negation, I assume it means I HAVE been speaking Spanish daily for years.

Comment: Over six years later, I was discussing this scenario with another Spanish-as-a-second language speaker and here's the breakdown of how I now translate this in my head in order to keep it straight:
"Hace años" = "It has been years"
"que no" = "since"
That is, "since" is a kind of negation in English.  Depending on the context, in English, you might say "It has been years since I HAVEN'T spoken Spanish daily." to convey you've been regularly speaking it for years.  A kind of "double negative" that Spanish doesn't require and was the source of my confusion.